# Using `sleep` makes pipe to not work

Tags: ruby, pipeline

I have this `oprint` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

amount = 100
index = 0
loop do
  index += 1
  if index % 5 == 0
    amount += 10
  end

  sleep 0.1
  $stdout.puts amount
end
```

If I run `oprint | echo`, then I don't see anything. If I comment out the `sleep 0.1` inside `oprint`, then I see a lot of output. Does `sleep` break the pipe? Is there a fix?

Comment: Get idea from here - https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/152548 ?

Comment: Add `$stdout.flush` after `$stdout.puts` solve the problem. Curious to learn why.

Comment: On my OS (mac os x, zsh) your program with commented `sleep` fills up the pipe and ends with exception `Broken pipe - <STDOUT> (Errno::EPIPE)`. IMO it is the expected behaviour

Comment: And does `echo` taking a stding? If you do `echo "something" | echo`, you will not see the string "something"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oprint | echo` really shouldn't work, because `echo` doesn't read from the input stream. It echos its arguments. If you want to test a simple pipe, `oprint | cat` would be more appropriate.

Even then, you should add `$stdout.flush` after the `puts` when you have an infinite loop like that. Since lots of small IO calls can be a performance bottleneck, Ruby buffers its output by default - meaning it stores up lots of little output in a buffer and then writes the whole buffer all at once. Flushing the buffer manually ensures that it won't end up waiting forever to do the actual write.

Making those two changes gives me the expected output.